# C# Design Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, programming-languages

I'm new to C# Programming, I'm having three events like Mouse Key Down,Up and Drag.

On all this events I need to repaint the screen. Is there any Design pattern to do this.

Since, I need to call this Repaint method repeatedly on each events??

Comment: what architecture? winforms? wpf? that is far more important than the language... also; why would you need a *design pattern* for that?

Comment: Win CE platform,Winforms and not wpf.My problem is generic if we need to call the same method again and again is there a design pattern to implement it.

Comment: ah yes; we can't possibly *call a method* if we can alternatively wrap it up in layers of abstraction - sounds enterprisey ;p

Comment: Could you brief how can I achieve it using abstraction?

Comment: If you are deciding to use a design pattern in the mentioned scenario, it might very well turn to be an antipattern. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three events and you want to call `Repaint` from all of them.  That's three lines of code.  Any abstraction you do to try to hide that repainting is going to cost you way more than three lines of code so you need a much more complicated use case before you can justify a more complex solution than just putting `Repaint` into each of your three event handlers.

**Edit:**

I want to add that you are taking a lot of heat for your question and I for one do not agree.  I think It's a simple sincere question and one asked clearly.  It's actually a great beginner design question: "Should I use abstraction in such-and-such situation?"  So, no, I don't think you should in this situation.  But good for you for trying to use abstraction every chance you get and don't worry because you will get plenty of legitimate reasons soon enough!

Comment: Okay It seems to be not possible,Just now I'm having three events but in feature it may go beyond that So,I had asked the question on that perspective.

Comment: @LokiDil: It is **possible** but sometimes the simplest solution is the best, even if it invokes a little repetition.  It makes the code easier to read and understand.  Save the big designs for the big problems.

Comment: thanks man you are the one who understand my question correctly, And basically I'm the beginner and analyzing each problem in a experts view thats why I had asked it has the ready-made solution using some Design Patterns.